# Cron execution not normal

Tags: cron

When I run `job.sh` in terminal, it works. In there there's just following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user
node script.js > file
```

When I run it from CRON, it just creates file and no text is there, if I run it manually, it's scripts output there...

Any reasons why?

Comment: Try using the full path to `node`.

Comment: Also see if there are any messages from CRON in `/var/mail/user`. If there is a working local mail service on the host, any error messages from user's cron jobs will end up there.

Comment: What's the exact line you're using in `cron`? If you don't redirect _stdout_ and _stderr_ please try again with the entire command wrapped like this, `( …your command to run job.sh here… ) >"$HOME/cron.log" 2>&1` and then look in `~/cron.log` for any error messages. If the solution doesn't become obvious please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/753072/edit) to include the new information (and if it does stand out to you then either write your own answer or delete the question, depending on how useful you think it might be to others)

Comment: Thank you. @jordanm you are right...After told me, I found there msg, that it doesn't know node. I used full path and will see if it's working

Comment: @roaima Thank you.

Comment: cron jobs do not have the same environment variables as your interactive shell.  They have a pared-down minimal environment.  In particular, PATH in cron is set to something minimal like `/usr/bin:/bin` and SHELL is set to `/bin/sh` by default.  This is well known and documented in `man cron` and `man 5 crontab` and many other places (incl. many Q&A about it on this site - PATH & environment issues are probably the most common cron-related questions here). You can set PATH and other env vars in the crontab and/or in any script run by cron.

Answer (score 1):

After wrapping my command to capture *stdout* and *stderr*, like this, I found I needed to provide full path of `node`:

```
( ./job.sh ) >"$HOME/cron.log" 2>&1
```

Also, it required a username for the database access, which it did not while not using `cron`.

`job.sh` was updated with following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user
/fullPathToNode/node script.js > file
```

Comment: and you show the full path to `node` in what line?

Comment: @VlastimilBurián In the job.sh